# How to make a variable in a string lowercase?

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting, lowercase

I have seen this Lab assignment on here already and I chose a different route to get the same result.  However I keep getting dinged on the case of the variable.  The input is inserted in capital, but when I use the variable in a string I get dinged because its uppercase.  Any thoughts on a easy way to change it?

```
menu = {'Oil change' : 35, 'Tire rotation' : 19, 'Car wash' : 7}

service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n') #Zylab enters using Oil change uppercase O

print('You entered:', service)

if (service in menu):
    print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(service, menu.get(service))) #inserting into the string as uppercase but as part of the sentence needs to be lower case.
else:
    print('Error: Requested service is not recognized')
```

I tried on line 8 to use:

```
print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(service.lower, menu.get(service))) #No good

print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format.lower(service, menu.get(service))) #Not god either
```

I am still struggling a with formatting placements or if it is even possible.

Comment: Please add the input and expected outputs to this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the line 8 to:

```
print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(service.lower(), menu.get(service)))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  So I was on the right track, I just didn't realize I needed the extra parentheses after lower.  I really appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this, Pretty simple!

```
menu = {'Oil change' : 35, 'Tire rotation' : 19, 'Car wash' : 7}

service = input('Enter desired auto service:\n').capitalize() #Zylab enters using Oil change uppercase O

print('You entered:', service)
menu_lower=[service.lower()  for service,price in menu.items()]
if service.lower() in menu_lower:
    print('Cost of {}: ${}'.format(service, menu.get(service))) #inserting into the string as uppercase but as part of the sentence needs to be lower case.
else:
    print('Error: Requested service is not recognized')
```

Comment: I had thought about adding another menu for lower case variable, but got hung up on trying to just make the initial variable lower.  I was getting the correct output, just with 1 capital letter.  I appreciate the suggestion.

I am curious.  on line 3 when you added .capitalize() , would that capitalize the entire variable or just the first letter?

Comment: capitalize() function only Capitalizes first letter followed by a space upper() function is used to capitalize all letters joined together in a string!